# C# code has "cannot resolve symbol" errors, cannot figure out why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have got this code to replace entities. However it will not build for me. I will be using it in a static help classer in ASP.NET 4.5. I keep getting "cannot resolve symbol" errors for the entities.

Code:

```
public static class HtmlCleaner
{
   public static string FixEntities(string html)  
    {
        NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();  
        nvc.Add(""", "&ldquo;");  
        nvc.Add(""", "&rdquo;");  
        nvc.Add("Ã¢â‚¬â€œ", "&mdash;");  

        foreach (string key in nvc.Keys)  
        {
            html = html.Replace(key, nvc[key]);  
        }

        return html;  
    }
}
```

Code sourced from: [Code Source](http://blog.codinghorror.com/cleaning-words-nasty-html/)

Thoughts?

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: Are you not using an IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `"` inside the quotes:

`nvc.Add("\"", "&ldquo;");`

Comment: Thanks @djs, You get the answer as first in. Very useful answer. Therefore unsure why this question warrants a -1?

Comment: While i didn't personally downvote it, it is probably because this question is essentially a typo. Future users will not get much benefit from this question or the answer. But thanks for posting; glad i could help!

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape " inside a "" so the correct way should be

```
nvc.Add("\"", "&ldquo;");
```